# How do I refer to an image using CSS for a Sproutcore app?

Tags: resources, static, sproutcore, css

All,

Simple question: I want to include an image "logo.png" as the background for my-app. Where should I put the file and how should I refer to it in the CSS file which is in the resources folder along with the main_page.js?

Here is the rest of the story:

I have a CSS class called doc-background. I know this class works because when I set the color of the background in a CSS file like so:
`.doc-background { background-color: red}` it has the desired effect and Firebug shows me that the class doc-background is being used.

However, when I add a line like
`.doc-background { background-image: url('logo.png'); }`, there is no effect. Firebug shows that the class doc-background is not applied. And when I modify the style in Firebug to add the line about the background-image it says "Failed to load URL" in the tooltip.

Can someone please point me to a guide on how to work with resources and images and where to put them if I want to use CSS? I have successfully used them using the image-view and coding them into the HTML.

Here is what I have already tried:

- Using static-url instead
- Moving the image file to images folder under resources
- Referred to the image by using all variations on the path  - including resources/images only including images, not including either...
- Lot of Googling for the answer, Reading create your own app tutorials etc.

If you have an example app that uses colors and images from a CSS that will be the ultimate! But a location and some help with the `background-image` CSS property will get me started!

Thanks much,

Vis

Comment: Are your sure the image is in the same dir as the file?

Comment: Did you mean 'absolute' path instead of static-url? I would try that for debugging purposes. Example: Your image is in a folder called 'images' in your root folder. For the background style call the exact url of the image `background:url('http://www.yoursite.com/images/image.jpg') top left;` It may be trying to grab the image from a folder whose path does not match from where it is being called.

Answer (score 4):

Place your image somewhere relative to your css:

resources/style.css 
  resources/images/logo.png

Then use static_url to refer to the image:

`background-image: static_url('images/logo.png');`